# ClickOnce deployment with more than one application, file groups

Tags: clickonce

I have a collection of .NET 4 (C#) applications and a program suite which has references to all the other applications and mainly consists of several buttons to start each of the applications. The program suite and all the applications are all deployed in one single ClickOnce deployment. As the program suite is the entry point of the deployment, it is the only part of the software which 'knows' about the ClickOnce deployment, i.e. where `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed == true` and where I can use `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment`.
Is there any way to make my other applications aware of the ClickOnce deployment as well?

What I want to achieve is to add a download file group to the ClickOnce deployment in a way that I can trigger the download not from the suite but from one of the other applications.